# Linked list binary insertion sort, error 216, sometimes works

Tags: algorithm, sorting, pascal

I am trying to implement binary insertion sort in a linked list. The program compiles fine and works about every third time a run it. It throws error 216 - General Protection fault (probably dereferencing a nil pointer). It is not the first time I've run into this problem when working with linked lists in Pascal and still I have no idea what causes it and why it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't. Thanks for any advice.

Code sample is [here](http://tny.cz/4f0e49be)

EDIT: The culprit must be somewhere in this while loop:

```
while (y^.next <> original.tail) do begin
    y:=original.takeOutFirst;
    l := 1; r := i-1;
    while (l<=r) do begin
            m := (l+r) div 2;
            x := sorted.itemNumber(m);
            if x^.data > y^.data then r:= m-1
            else l:=m+1
    end;
    x := sorted.ItemNumber(l);
    sorted.insertInsteadOf(x, y);
    inc(i);
```

end;

Comment: Can you post the minimum code necessary to demonstrate the issue within your question? You can use the "code" button in the SO editor to format it nicely.

Comment: Can you guarantee that `y` will always be not nil?

Comment: @PaulNathan Yes, I think so. All the elements of the y list should not be nil. Just tail^.next is nil, but it should never be reached.

Comment: @PaulNathan It doesn't make any sense :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the sample, on line 13, I changed i:=2 to i:=1 and the code miraculously works. Why?!